# Why does my BQL to select from the database return the current screen's '<NEW>' record?

Tags: acumatica

I have BLC code in the Sales Order screen (SO301000) that uses the RowSelected event to determine whether a CustomerOrderNbr exists for another customer, and to do this, I'm using the following BQL to obtain previously saved records:

```
//Retrieving the order related to the customer order number
SOOrder soorder2 = PXSelect<SOOrder,
                   Where<SOOrder.customerOrderNbr, Equal<Required<SOOrder.customerOrderNbr>>,
                   And<SOOrder.customerID, Equal<Required<SOOrder.customerID>>,
                   And<Where<SOOrder.orderType, Equal<Constants.qt>,
                       Or<SOOrder.orderType, Equal<Constants.fi>,
                       Or<SOOrder.orderType, Equal<Constants.fo>,
                       Or<SOOrder.orderType, Equal<Constants.fr>>>>>>>>>.Select(Base, soorder.CustomerOrderNbr, soorder.CustomerID);
```

We never noticed this problem until 2019 R2 - where this BQL select is now bringing back the records currently on the screen, with " <NEW>" as the OrderNbr.  I don't want this - I want what's saved in the database.

How can I stop this BQL from returning unsaved current screen records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could filter them out using `tstamp` field:

```
Where<SOOrder.tstamp, IsNotNull>
```

Records will have a null tstamp value until they are persisted in database.

Comment: But the question remains - why would it bring back the unsaved screen's information, including a <NEW> Order number?...  Pretty sure it's never done this before...

Comment: I'm not so sure, if the records are inserted in cache I can see how they merge with DB records.